# Xcode CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

Updated my iPad to the iOS 8 GM seed and am using the Xcode 6 GM seed. Tried building my previously working and submitted app on my device and am getting a "build failed" with the above error. Have tried restarting Xcode, cleaning the build, and re-pulling all of my profiles from the Accounts panel in Xcode, all to no avail. Another developer on my team is using the same profiles with the same applications and he's not having any issues, so I'm not too sure what the deal is and all of the info on this issue is kind of outdated as Xcode has been updated a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it ended up being was I updated Xcode and it had somehow hard-coded an old provisioning profile in there, making it impossible for me to change to any others, so I had to open up the project file in a text editor and delete the line of code that was hard-setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem.
Not sure why but generating a new profile in the dev portal fixed this issue for me.